# Number of faces of a certain convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hulls

Imagine a convex hull of n points in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The coordinates of the vertices of the convex hull are as follows:

$$p_a = (a, a^2, a^3, a^4) \ \ \text{for} \ \ a = 1, ..., n$$. I want to prove that the number of faces in the convex hull is at least proportional to $n^2$.

Is it enough to say that each point must have a face connecting with each other point meaning that there are, at a minimum, $n^2$ total faces in the convex hull?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: At most $\binom{n}{5}$.

Comment: I have attempted to better the presentation of your question. I wish you don't object.